# How to set literal string values in Doctrine Update queries?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-1.2, string-literals, doctrine-query

For doctrine 1.2, I find plenty of examples like these:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
->update('mytable')
->set('amount', 'amount+200')
->whereIn ('id', $ids);
```

What I want to do however is a different set:

```
->set('name', 'foo bar')
```

This however, leads to exception. Of course, because foo is no column, like amount.
No luck with `'´foo bar´'` either. How can I clarify foo bar is a string literal?

I believe [this](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_query_abstract.html#set%28%29) is the right place to look, but I don't find further info.
Also: I would love to know more about the 'mixed params' and 'string update' mentioned there. Perhaps there's a DOCTRINE::FLAG_LITERAL or such?

Comment: Apparently, here is an answer. But I habe yet to understand, how Doctrine knows, if e.g. "John" is a column or a literal...: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803436/update-multiple-columns-with-doctrine-in-symfony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
->set('name', '?', 'foo bar')
```

This is the equivalent of doing the following in DQL

```
SET name = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use :

```php
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->update('mytable')
    ->set('name', ':name')
    ->setParameter('name', 'foo bar')
```